# pyspark replace multiple values with null in dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe (`df`) and within the dataframe I have a column `user_id`

```python
df = sc.parallelize([(1, "not_set"),
                     (2, "user_001"),
                     (3, "user_002"),
                     (4, "n/a"),
                     (5, "N/A"),
                     (6, "userid_not_set"),
                     (7, "user_003"),
                     (8, "user_004")]).toDF(["key", "user_id"])
```

df:

```python
+---+--------------+
|key|       user_id|
+---+--------------+
|  1|       not_set|
|  2|      user_003|
|  3|      user_004|
|  4|           n/a|
|  5|           N/A|
|  6|userid_not_set|
|  7|      user_003|
|  8|      user_004|
+---+--------------+
```

I would like to replace the following values: `not_set`, `n/a`, `N/A` and `userid_not_set` with null.

It would be good if I could add any new values to a list and they to could be changed.

I am currently using a CASE statement within **spark.sql** to preform this and would like to change this to pyspark.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`None` inside the `when()` function corresponds to the `null`. In case you wish to fill in anything else instead of `null`, you have to fill it in it's place.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col    
df =  df.withColumn(
    "user_id",
    when(
        col("user_id").isin('not_set', 'n/a', 'N/A', 'userid_not_set'),
        None
    ).otherwise(col("user_id"))
)
df.show()
+---+--------+
|key| user_id|
+---+--------+
|  1|    null|
|  2|user_001|
|  3|user_002|
|  4|    null|
|  5|    null|
|  6|    null|
|  7|user_003|
|  8|user_004|
+---+--------+
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that `when` returns `null` if the condition fails and no `otherwise` is supplied. So in this case, the following is equivalent, but a little more succinct: `df.withColumn("user_id", when(~col("user_id").isin('not_set', 'n/a', 'N/A', 'userid_not_set'), col("user_id")))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the in-built `when` function, which is the equivalent of a `case` expression.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df.select(df.key,f.when(df.user_id.isin(['not_set', 'n/a', 'N/A']),None).otherwise(df.user_id)).show()
```

Also the values needed can be stored in a `list` and be referenced.

```
val_list = ['not_set', 'n/a', 'N/A']
df.select(df.key,f.when(df.user_id.isin(val_list),None).otherwise(df.user_id)).show()
```

Comment: I get this error "name 'null' is not defined", if I change the null to a string then it works.

Answer (score 0):

PFB few approaches. I am assuming that all the legitimate user IDs starts with `"user_"`. Please try below code.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.withColumn(
    "user_id",
    when(col("user_id").startswith("user_"),col("user_id")).otherwise(None)
).show()
```

Another One.

```python
cond = """case when user_id in ('not_set', 'n/a', 'N/A', 'userid_not_set') then null
                else user_id
            end"""

df.withColumn("ID", expr(cond)).show()
```

Another One.

```python
cond = """case when user_id like 'user_%' then user_id
                else null
            end"""

df.withColumn("ID", expr(cond)).show()
```

Another one.

```python
df.withColumn(
    "user_id",
    when(col("user_id").rlike("user_"),col("user_id")).otherwise(None)
).show()
```